# Llamar un modal después de realizar una validación con FLASK

Tags: python, flask

Llevo una semana aprendiendo flask para pasarme al entorno web con python mi duda es como logro llamar a un modal una vez que realice una función que verifica si los datos existen en una bd  mostrando un mensaje que envía el servidor, el mensaje por el servidor es "EL USUARIO NO EXISTE" caso contrario devolver el nombre del usuario encontrado. Espero me sepan ayudar con un pequeño ejemplo, desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse su tiempo de ayudarme.

Comment: javascript con bootstrap?

Comment: si mi modal esta diseñado con bootstrap

Comment: Igual puedes usar JavaScript

Comment: me ayudarías con un pequeño ejemplo de como hacerlo, como dije llevo muy poco con flask y la verdad lo estoy aprendiendo por cuenta mía no tengo profesor al que consultarle muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Te publico un ejemplo que tiene que ver junto con el modal que mencionas, este verifica ciertos datos par una encuesta, pero igual lo puedes adaptar

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulario" action="javascript:guardarEncuesta();" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <h3><strong>Registro</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <br><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <input type="checkbox" id="registro" checked data-toggle="toggle">
<</div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div id="contenido">
<br>
 <div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="dato1" name="dato1" placeholder="Agrega Campo para Registro" required></div>
 <div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="padding: 7px; width: 30px;border-radius: 25px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="agregarRegistro();"><center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></center></button></div>
   </div>
<input type="hidden" id="cuantosR" name="cuantosR" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="cuantosP" name="cuantosP" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="cuantosO" name="cuantosO" value="1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Si te das cuenta en el boton "onclick" mando a llamar al modal por medio de JS

y aqui esta el modal, verifica datos como te mencione, y si todo esta bien, da una respuesta de Success y si no marca error

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-guardar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
                <img src="{{asset('assets/images/signo.png')}}">
    <h3><strong style="color: white">¿Desea guardar la encuesta?</strong></h3>
    <p style="color: white">
 Una vez hecha la encuesta, no se podrá modificar.
</p>
  </center>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-exito" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-body">
<center>
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/singo1.png')}}">
  <h3><strong style="color: white">Éxito</strong></h3>
  <p style="color: white">
 Tu encuesta se ha guardado exitosamente.
 </p>
</center>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
<a href="{{URL::action('EncuestaEspecificaController@index')}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar</button></a>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-error" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<center>
 <img src="{{asset('assets/images/signo2.png')}}">
    <h3 style="color: white"><strong>Error</strong></h3>
                                                        <p style="color: white">
Hubo un problema al guardar tu encuesta.
</p>
  </center>
  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6" align="left">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

y Aqui viene otra cosa que desconosco si sea compatible con flask que es ajax
que esta parte donde mando los datos a mi BD o a mi controlador para que se guarde

```
function guardarEncuesta(){
            var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('formulario'));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/guardarEspecifica',
                type: 'post',
                data: form,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#modal-guardar").modal('hide');
                    $("#modal-exito").modal('show');
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#modal-guardar").modal('hide');
                    $("#modal-error").modal('show');
                }
            });
    }
```